I would like to add a new column per row that is a sequence based on the start and end column
For example if the data frame is as
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","b"),start = c(2,5),end = c(3,10))

then the output should be


One way to solve your problem:
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  reframe(sequence=start:end, .by=c(ID, start, end))

  ID start end sequence
1  a     2   3        2
2  a     2   3        3
3  b     5  10        5
4  b     5  10        6
5  b     5  10        7
6  b     5  10        8
7  b     5  10        9
8  b     5  10       10


One option:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.frame(
  ID = c("a", "b"),
  Start = c(2, 5),
  End = c(3, 10)
) |>
  mutate(Sequence = list(Start:End), .by = 1) |>
  unnest(Sequence)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   ID    Start   End Sequence
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>    <int>
#> 1 a         2     3        2
#> 2 a         2     3        3
#> 3 b         5    10        5
#> 4 b         5    10        6
#> 5 b         5    10        7
#> 6 b         5    10        8
#> 7 b         5    10        9
#> 8 b         5    10       10

Created on 2024-06-04 with reprex v2.1.0

This solution requires that there are no duplicates by ID, which doesn't seem a part of your problem
len <- df$end - df$start + 1
seq <- mapply(`:`, df$start, df$end)
df <- df[rep.int(1:nrow(df), len), ]
df$sequence <- unlist(seq)

> df
    ID start end sequence
1    a     2   3        2
1.1  a     2   3        3
2    b     5  10        5
2.1  b     5  10        6
2.2  b     5  10        7
2.3  b     5  10        8
2.4  b     5  10        9
2.5  b     5  10       10


You can use Map(seq, start, end), followed by unnest
df %>%
  mutate(seqs = Map(seq, start, end)) %>%
  unnest(seqs)

which gives
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  ID    start   end  seqs
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1 a         2     3     2
2 a         2     3     3
3 b         5    10     5
4 b         5    10     6
5 b         5    10     7
6 b         5    10     8
7 b         5    10     9
8 b         5    10    10

